# Match the value in matrix to further display column name and row name

Tags: matrix

The table iam having is a matrix of 4000 rows X 4000 columns, sample of it is as given below:

```
TaxonA/B    GBCAT-01    GBCAT-02    GBCAT-03    GBCAT-04
GBCAT-01    100 81.1    100 81.4
GBCAT-02    81.1    100 79.9    82.2
GBCAT-03    100 79.9    100 81.6
GBCAT-04    81.4    82.2    81.6    100
```

I need to match the value for example say, 100 in the matrix above and display the match column name and row name as below

```
Taxon A TaxonB
GBCAT-01    GBCAT-01
GBCAT-01    GBCAT-02
GBCAT-02    GBCAT-02
GBCAT-03    GBCAT-01
GBCAT-03    GBCAT-03
GBCAT-04    GBCAT-04
```

Please suggest the formula,
Help appereciated! thank you!